# SLURM/NFS cluster shared filesystem locked permissions on some users

Tags: module, conda, cluster-computing, slurm, nfs

### Background

I used slurm to set up a 3-node cluster, one control node and 3 compute nodes (the control node doubles as a compute node). All of the nodes are on linux mint and they all communicate through a shared filesystem and a tailscale network.
The shared filesystem is /opt/opt-shared/ and is mounted on boot on all nodes.

### Immediate goal

Setting up a module that activates and uses any conda env stored on the shared filesystem. The idea is the miniconda3/ dir holding all the conda files and envs is in a specific folder within the shared filesystem so when a slurm script is sent to the queue, any of the nodes should be able to source anything it needs from that dir.

### Problem

When I send a slurm script to the queue, depending on the user that is sending it, I get varying behaviors. Let's say root user A on the compute node sends this test script via 'sbatch':

```bash
#!/bin/bash 
#SBATCH --job-name=stress-test
#SBATCH --time=00:30:00
#SBATCH --cpus-per-task=16
#SBATCH --output=/opt/opt-shared/input-files/stresstest/out.out
#SBATCH --error=/opt/opt-shared/input-files/stresstest/error.err

source /etc/profile.d/modules.sh
module load conda
source activate stress

srun stress-ng --cpu 0 --cpu-method all --timeout 30s --metrics-brief
```

This runs exactly as I'd expect, and I can even specify nodes=3, or call specific nodes, and everything runs great. Then, running from non-root user B, I get in the error.err:

> ```py
> KeyError('pkgs_dirs')
> Traceback (most recent call last):
> File "/opt/opt-shared/miniconda3/lib/python3.11/site-packages/conda/exception_handler.py", line 17, in __call__
> return func(*args, **kwargs)
>            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
> File "/opt/opt-shared/miniconda3/lib/python3.11/site-packages/conda/cli/main.py", line 92, in main_sourced
> context.__init__()
> File "/opt/opt-shared/miniconda3/lib/python3.11/site-packages/conda/base/context.py", line 456, in __init__
> self._set_search_path(
> File "/opt/opt-shared/miniconda3/lib/python3.11/site-packages/conda/common/configuration.py", line 1426, in _set_search_path
> self._search_path = IndexedSet(self._expand_search_path(search_path, **kwargs))
>                     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
> File "/opt/opt-shared/miniconda3/lib/python3.11/site-packages/boltons/setutils.py", line 125, in __init__
> self.update(other)
> File "/opt/opt-shared/miniconda3/lib/python3.11/site-packages/boltons/setutils.py", line 355, in update
> for o in other:
> File "/opt/opt-shared/miniconda3/lib/python3.11/site-packages/conda/common/configuration.py", line 1399, in _expand_search_path
> if path.is_file() and (
>    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
> File "/opt/opt-shared/miniconda3/lib/python3.11/pathlib.py", line 1267, in is_file
> return S_ISREG(self.stat().st_mode)
>                ^^^^^^^^^^^
> File "/opt/opt-shared/miniconda3/lib/python3.11/pathlib.py", line 1013, in stat
> return os.stat(self, follow_symlinks=follow_symlinks)
>        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
> PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/home/<userb>/.config/conda/.condarc'
>
> During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):
> File "/opt/opt-shared/miniconda3/lib/python3.11/site-packages/conda/exception_handler.py", line 165, in print_unexpected_error_report
> get_main_info_str(error_report["conda_info"])
> File "/opt/opt-shared/miniconda3/lib/python3.11/site-packages/conda/cli/main_info.py", line 254, in get_main_info_str
> info_dict[f"_{key}"] = ("\n" + 26 * " ").join(map(str, info_dict[key]))
>                                                        ~~~~~~~~~^^^^^
> KeyError: 'pkgs_dirs'
>
> ERROR REPORT <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):
> File "/opt/opt-shared/miniconda3/lib/python3.11/site-packages/conda/exception_handler.py", line 17, in __call__
> return func(*args, **kwargs)
>        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
> File "/opt/opt-shared/miniconda3/lib/python3.11/site-packages/conda/cli/main.py", line 92, in main_sourced
> context.__init__()
> File "/opt/opt-shared/miniconda3/lib/python3.11/site-packages/conda/base/context.py", line 456, in __init__
> self._set_search_path(
> File "/opt/opt-shared/miniconda3/lib/python3.11/site-packages/conda/common/configuration.py", line 1426, in _set_search_path
> self._search_path = IndexedSet(self._expand_search_path(search_path, **kwargs))
>                     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
> File "/opt/opt-shared/miniconda3/lib/python3.11/site-packages/boltons/setutils.py", line 125, in __init__
> self.update(other)
> File "/opt/opt-shared/miniconda3/lib/python3.11/site-packages/boltons/setutils.py", line 355, in update
> for o in other:
> File "/opt/opt-shared/miniconda3/lib/python3.11/site-packages/conda/common/configuration.py", line 1399, in _expand_search_path
> if path.is_file() and (
>    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
> File "/opt/opt-shared/miniconda3/lib/python3.11/pathlib.py", line 1267, in is_file
> return S_ISREG(self.stat().st_mode)
>                ^^^^^^^^^^^
> File "/opt/opt-shared/miniconda3/lib/python3.11/pathlib.py", line 1013, in stat
> return os.stat(self, follow_symlinks=follow_symlinks)
>        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
> PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/home/<userb>/.config/conda/.condarc'
>
> `$ /opt/opt-shared/miniconda3/bin/conda shell.posix activate stress`
>
> environment variables:
> conda info could not be constructed.
> KeyError('pkgs_dirs')
>
> An unexpected error has occurred. Conda has prepared the above report.
> If you suspect this error is being caused by a malfunctioning plugin,
> consider using the --no-plugins option to turn off plugins.
>
> Example: conda --no-plugins install <package>
>
> Alternatively, you can set the CONDA_NO_PLUGINS environment variable on
> the command line to run the command without plugins enabled.
>
> Example: CONDA_NO_PLUGINS=true conda install <package>
> ```

In case it's relevant, the modules.sh on each node is actually a symlink to a central modules.sh file on the shared filesystem. Doubt this changes anything, but you never know. Also, the user that can successfully send the job is the one that conda was originally installed on, and if I add the flag [ #SBATCH --export=NONE ] this breaks the job even for this user, which hints at some temporary shell environment variable being inherited by the shell created for the specific job on the compute nodes, but I cannot find which one it might be.

Now, to get rid of any permission shennanigans, I simply did `chmod -R 777` on the miniconda3/ dir. This didn't change anything. I tried looking in my NFS mount & export settings to see if there was any other permission squashing but then again nothing.

Now, when attempting to manually run the info command using:

```bash
/opt/opt-shared/miniconda3/bin/conda info
```

I found some interesting things. If I run this normally & manually from a compute node, I get the same permission error. However running as sudo from the COMPUTE NODE I can get through. Same thing when running the 'sbatch' command as sudo. These behaviors are weird to me because I thought NFS enabled root squashing by default, and also because the dir has already been chmodded to 777, so yeah, idk. To make matters even more confusing the other node already had conda on it so there's a ton of confusing conflicts - for now I'll just focus on the first compute node, since this one was freshly formatted.

As additional info, here's the corresponding modulefile:

```bash
#%Module1.0
set root /opt/opt-shared/miniconda3
prepend-path PATH $root/bin
```

If any wonderful soul out there could help me set up this conda module I would heavily appreciate it. For context, I work on a research team that needs to send tons of concurrent calculations, and everyone has their own conda envs, so this setup seemed like the best way to handle things.

I tried changing the shared filesystem ownership and permissions since the error I'm getting is a permission error. This didn't help, still getting permission errors from the compute nodes.

I tried manually combing through the shell environment variables on the user that was successfully completing jobs with the conda module, and comparing it to those that were failing. The idea was to find discrepancies and maybe manually export the necessary env variable(s) in the slurm script instead of depending on inheritance, but I couldn't pinpoint which env variable(s) would work like this.

To isolate the issue further, I attempted to manually run conda commands on many different users on all the nodes, trying to see if there was an issue in how one of the machines was using the NFS shared filesystem, but honestly all I could find was that giving sudo privileges to the processes fixed the problems, which I truly don't understand.

I tried echoing a bunch of env variables inside of the slurm script to get a better understanding of how the compute nodes were trying to access the conda files, but they all seem to be pointing at the correct dirs in the shared filesystem, so again no luck.

Comment: *"`'/home//.config/conda/.condarc'`"* Are you masking the username? or specifically what user is running the script? Seems more like a non-existent file than a permissions issue. Unfortunately, I don't know how this config should behave - we recommend all users install Miniforge locally (including running `conda init`/`mamba init`) and SLURM shell submissions should use the shebang `#!/bin/bash -l` which enables `conda activate`/`source activate`. Not sure if that helps at all. I would recommend asking on [Conda Discourse](https://conda.discourse.group) instead.

Answer (score 0):

If you created the Conda environment with one user in their home directory and then moved it to a common filesystem, beware that there can be hardcoded paths in that installation that link back to the original user's home directory.

Moving a Conda environment cannot be done by simply `mv`'ing it. See [this page of the Conda doc](https://www.anaconda.com/blog/moving-conda-environments) for the proper way(s) to do it.

Since the `PermissionError` refers to a directory in `/home` this could be the issue.

Also make sure that all parents of the permissions are correct on all parents of the directory where Conda is installed. `chmod`'ing the Conda dir to `777` (better would have been `755`) is not sufficient in itself. The `namei -lx $(realpath <Conda dir>)` command can help here.